# Bootstrap 4: Full Width Inline Button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The title might be misleading, but I didn't know how else to name it.
In any case, I need to have an div/image inlined with a text, and a button beneath that text. The issue is, I can't really make the button take the full width without adding any padding, no matter what I try.

To make my explanation clearer, here's an image of what I'm trying to make:

[image]

And I'm trying to use Bootstrap 4 utilities only. 
This is my code so far:

```css
.col-md-3 {
  background-color: #ededed;
}
.img {
  width: 188px;
  height: 88px;
  background-color: #292a2c;
}
.btn {
  background-color: #292a2c;
  color: #ededed;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 d-flex p-0">
  <div class="img"></div>
    <div>
      <h6 class="m-auto">Text goes here</h6>
      <button class="btn rounded-0 btn-block">Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make this work? Also, the div with a class .img is a placeholder in a way, and needs to stay like that.

Thank you!

Comment: When you say "I'm trying to use Bootstrap 4 utilities only", do you mean you don't want to cause any style changes that are not made with a bootstrap class?

Comment: Yes. Basically. Only what Bootstrap 4 classes allow me to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using bootstrap media object with no additional css. Please see code snippet below

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="media">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/188x88" class="mr-3" alt="">
        <div class="media-body">
          <h5 class="mt-0">Media heading</h5>
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, then style it accordingly:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ79Qe630Fli9-SIDz188GQURmrRfhh6AksMKexPP5JvsE7AJ6t01mf5A">
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="row">
        <p>text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button>button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for getting as shown in the image

```
'<div class="col-md-12"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-3"><div class="row"><div class="img"></div></div></div>
<div class="col-md-6"><div class="row">
 <h6 class="m-auto">Text goes here</h6><button class="btn rounded-0 btn-block">Button</button></div></div></div>
```

For style use the style in your question

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

Note that Bootstrap by default does not have a black background class so you would have to create one.

```css
.bg-black {
  background-color: #000 !important;
  border: 2px solid #000 !important;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container-fluid">      <!-- Make it full width -->
  <div class="row d-flex">         <!-- display flex -->
    <div class="col-4 align-self-stretch">      <!-- stretch the column -->
      <img class="w-100" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-8 align-self-stretch">      <!-- stretch the column -->
      <p>Some Text Here.<br/> Can be long or short</p>
      <p>Yet another paragraph</p>
      <p>And one more paragraph</p>
      <button class="btn btn-primary bg-black btn-block rounded-0">Btn Txt</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
   .col-md-3 {
      background-color: #ededed;
      width:100% !important;
      
    }
    
   .col-md-3> div{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
     width: 60%;
     height:100%;
    }
    .img {
      width: 15% !important;;
      height: 88px !important;
      background-color: #292a2c;
      display:inline-block;
    }
    
    .btn {
      width: 60%;
      background-color: #292a2c;
      color: #ededed;
      height:50%;
      display:inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 d-flex p-0">
  <div class="img"></div>
    <div>
      <h6 class="m-auto">Text goes here</h6>
      <button class="btn rounded-0 btn-block">Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good just make sure that you have bootstrap.css file in right place and make sure that its working.

I made some changes to your code, its a bit hard coded but u must take care to overwrite bootstrap classes and don't change them directly.

```css
.box {
  background-color: #ededed;
}
.img {
  width: 188px;
  height: 88px;
  background-color: #292a2c;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.text {
  float: left;
}
.btn {
  background-color: #292a2c;
  color: #ededed;
  margin-top: 33px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-6 d-flex p-0">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <h6 class="m-auto">Text goes here</h6>
      <button class="btn rounded-0 btn-block">Button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```